# Regroups a list of products by order with regroup template tag

Tags: django

I'm having problems using {% regroup %} Django template tag. 
A brief summary: I succeed listing all my orders with their products ordered in the same template. So all seems to works fine doing the following:

1. Create the order
2. Create products ordered
3. Assing those products to the order
4. Display the daily orders with their products in the same template (filtered by date also) in dailyorders.html

Here my codes and only I'll show the code which allows me to display the orders and modify one if I want (where I have the problem)

models:

```
class Productsordered (models.Model):

    item            = models.ForeignKey(Itemlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order           = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity        = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quant} - {self.item.nombre_producto}"

class Orders(models.Model):

    date           = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    client_name    = models.CharField(max_length=30) (just name, not client id)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.client_name

class Itemlist(models.Model):
    id                = models.SlugField(primary_key = True, max_length =30)
    name_item         = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price             = models.IntegerField()
```

Just daily orders and modify order views:

```
def show_daily_orders(request,**kwargs):
    daily_products_ordered = 
    Productsordered.objects.filter(order__date__day=date.today().day,                                                    
                                   order__date__month=date.today().month,                                                           
                                   order__date__year=date.today().year)

    return render(request,'dailyorders.html',{'daily_products_ordered':daily_products_ordered})

def add_products_ordered (request,pk_order,pk_item):
    products_ordered=Productsordered.objects.filter(order=pk_order)
    get_order=Orders.objects.get(id=pk_pedido)
    list= Itemlist.objects.all()

#ask if the product is already there, if not create one
        try:
            product = products_ordered.get(item=pk_item)
            product.quantity += 1
            product.save()
        except:
            newproduct = Itemlist.objects.get(id=pk_item)
            newproduct = Productsordered.objects.create(item=newproduct, order=get_order)
            product.save()

        return render(request,'modify.html',{'list':list,'products_ordered':products_ordered,'order':order})
```

dailyorders.html would be something like:

```
{% regroup daily_products_ordered by order as order_list %}

{% for order in order_list %}
<h2> {{order.grouper}}   
   {% for product in order.list  %}
            <li> {{product.quantity}} - {{ product.item.name_item }}</li>
     <a class = 'btn' href="{% url 'go_to_modify_order' pk=order.grouper.id %}">Modify order</a>

   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

modify.html

```
{% for prod in list %}
                      <a class="btn" href="{% url 'go_to_modify_order' pk_item=prod.id pk_order=order.id %}">{{prod.name_item}}</a>

              {% endfor %}

<a class="btn" href="{% url 'go_to_orders' pk_item=prod.id pk_pedido=order.id %}"> Finish modifying order </a>


# Also there would be the choice to delete an added product, but no matter for the problem.
```

The problem is that when I try to modify an order and add a new product (simply clicking the buttons and adding them to the cart) when I return to the  template where I get all orders, regroup counts this new product as if it were from another order. For example:

Laura (**order_id=1**):

- Product A
- Product B

Carlos (order_id=2):

- Product X

Laura (**order_id=1**):

- Product C (this would be the product added when modify order!)

In order to see what happened, I went to the admin section and noticed that this new product is even added to the order I modified (Product C belonging to order_id=1 for example). So, it seems to be a problem when passing from the modify template to the daily orders, or something else I haven't noticed yet.

I'd appreciate help in this topic.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already done!

Seems to be that regroup only works when you have your dictionary order by the attribute you want to regroup! That's because I was getting the orders separately (see the example Laura (order_id=1) twice! see django documentation about regroup built-in template